# Python, separating if statements

Tags: python

I have been doing some python coding, and have come across an annoying bump. I have two if statements in a fairly large script:

```
    from datetime import datetime
answer_simpl = "worded_date"
if answer_simpl == "worded_date":
    now = datetime.now()
    day = now.day
    month = now.month
    year = now.year
if day == "1":
    num_th = "st"
elif day == "21":
    num_th = "st"
elif day == "31":
    num_th = "st"
elif day == "2":
    num_th = "nd"
elif day == "22":
    num_th = "nd"
elif day == "32":
    num_th = "nd"
elif day == "3":
    num_th = "rd"
elif day == "23":
    num_th = "rd"
else: num_th = "th"
if month == "1":
    month_word = "January"
elif month == "2":
    month_word = "Febuary"
elif month == "3":
    month_word = "March"
elif month == "4":
    month_word = "April"
elif month == "5":
    month_word = "May"
elif month == "6":
    month_word = "June"
elif month == "7":
    month_word = "July"
elif month == "8":
    month_word = "August"
elif month == "9":
    month_word = "September"
elif month == "10":
    month_word = "October"
elif month == "11":
    month_word = "November"
elif month == "12":
    month_word = "December"
print("The date is {}{} of".format(day,num_th),month_word,year)
```

When I run it, it works until it attempts to print "month_word". It says it is not defined and yet over 24 lines of code says other wise. I have tried many things and still can't find anything to fix it. I can't seem to find a way to define "month_word" because it thinks it is a part of the last "else:" statement. Is there some sort of command that can separate the statements? and is what I said true that it is a part of the last "else:". I could really use some help with this and any info on this would be very helpful!

Comment: Your code is wrong I think.
    now = datetime.now()
    day = now.day

day is an integer, the same for month.
So at least the code in the if statements never executes.
Moreover, you can replace the ifs with 2 dictionaries

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is because `day`, `month`, and `year` are integers, and you're comparing them to string values, so basically your second `if` statement will not execute any `month_word = ...` and hence the variable `month_word` won't be defined.

Change your conditions to integers e.g. `elif month == 5:`.

**Update**

Also try to think of a better implementation than this, something like:

```
import calendar
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
day = now.day
month = now.month
year = now.year

num_th = {1:  'st',
          21: 'st',
          31: 'st',
          2:  'nd',
          22: 'nd',
          3:  'rd'}.get(day, 'th')
month_word = calendar.month_name[month]

print("The date is {}{} of".format(day, num_th), month_word, year)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
elif month == 9: # you need to check against an integer
```

It will be easier to change month  to a string:  `month = str(now.month)`